# Приложение для визуализации из 1С?

Tags: javascript, 1с, webgl

На предприятии используют самописный софт для работы с номенклатурой из базы данных 1С (мебельная фурнитура итд.) Визуальная часть (работа с размерами, текстурой 2d графика) выполнена на Flash. Необходимо переписать программу с нуля.

Вопросы:
Какую технологию уместнее использовать? - думают на WebGL.
Реально ли освоить и внедрить это за пол года-год. Зная базовый JS,верстку. (Есть возможность получить работу и заниматься этим проектом, помимо в штате есть 1С программисты).

Comment: вебгл может оказаться здесь лишним, или слишком сложным, лучше поточнее описать функционал, который необходимо реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Любую удобную для Вас; Архитектура такого проекта обычно выглядит так: Flash-приложение читает/записывает данные в свою базу-данных (SQL) 1C забирает заказы, обновляет материалы самостоятельно по расписанию. При такой архитектуре - части проекта изолированы друг от друга. А это позволяет гибко и быстро вести разработку (ведь общего у них только формат базы данных)